# how to make certain css 3d effect works in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, transform

so i have this 3d transform effect, that works well in chrome, but having some problem in IE,

i've create the code sample in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jPuTL/2/)

and some of the 3d transform code:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 100%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 100%, 0px) rotateX(-90deg);
```

the problem is, the element would rotate -90 degree but isn't showing anything when rotated (in IE), any idea on how to fix it? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE Does not support:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d
```

[check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property)

regards

Shiva

Comment: okay, but is there any workaround or way to make it work on IE?

Comment: You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform.